# Trying to deploy on octopus but got variable error

Tags: octopus-deploy

I'm deploying to octopus server, and I got this error.

> An attempt to parse the variable symbol "AppPoolAccount" appears to have resulted in a self referencing loop (AppPoolAccount -> AppPoolAccount). Ensure that recursive loops do not exist in the variable values.

Comment: sounds like a possible variable [substitution issues](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/variables/variable-substitutions)

Comment: Perhaps more people could help you if you told us more information. How is that variable defined in your project? And if that variable uses other variables, how are they defined. What makes you think that the error message isn't telling you *exactly* what the problem is? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please take a look at the uploaded image. https://imgur.com/Qt2JfH9

Comment: May I suggest that you also read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5198140)